# C# Call function from another form (radform)

Tags: c#, mysql, methods, call

First of all, I would like to point out that I have searched for a solution to this problem without luck.

So basicly I have a Mysql function in Radform1 witch I want to call from CustomAppointmentEditForm

**Radform1**

```
  public RadForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

**CustomAppointmentEditForm**

```
        public CustomAppointmentEditForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

The function I want to call from Radform1

```
private void Update_LeadInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
            {
                string UniqueID = textBoxDescription.Text;

                string CVR = txtCVR.Text;
                string Firma = txtFirma.Text;
                string Nummer = txtNummer.Text;
                string Addresse = txtAddresse.Text;
                string Postnr = txtPostnr.Text;
                string By = txtBy.Text;
                string Noter = txtNoter.Text;
                string Email = txtEmail.Text;
                string StartDato = dateStart.Text + " " + timeStart.Text;
                string SlutDato = dateEnd.Text + " " + timeEnd.Text;
                string Afholdt = radCheckBox1.CheckState.ToString();
                if(Afholdt == "Checked")
                {
                    Afholdt = "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    Afholdt = "0";
                }
                if(chkAllDay.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                {
                    StartDato = dateStart.Text + " " + "00:00";
                    SlutDato = dateEnd.Text + " " + "00:00";
                }
                cn.Open();

                Console.WriteLine(UniqueID);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Leads SET CVR = ('" + CVR + "'), Firma = ('" + Firma + "'), Nummer = ('" + Nummer + "'), Addresse = ('" + Addresse + "'), Postnr = ('" + Postnr + "'), Bynavn = ('" + By + "'), Noter = ('" + Noter + "'), Afholdt = ('" + Afholdt + "'), Email = ('" + Email + "'), Slut_Dato = ('" + SlutDato + "')  WHERE UniqueID = ('" + UniqueID + "');";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.Dispose();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Fejl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Fejl);
        }
    }
```

I know there is a simple solution to this, thanks in advance

Comment: You need a reference of `Radform1` in your `CustomAppointmentEditForm`. This has been asked quadtrillion times here already.

Comment: Could you give an example? As said, I'm working with Radforms, there's a little diffirence

Comment: `Radform1 formObj = new Radform1();` then call the show method like this `formObj.Update_LeadInfo();`

Comment: @Taco2 There's no difference at all. OOP stays OOP independent of any frameworks, libraries , etc. you're using.

Comment: How will that trigger the function?

Comment: Alright, could you give an example?

Comment: I think @un-lucky meant `formObj.Update_LeadInfo()`.

Comment: `searched for a solution to this problem without luck` where and what have you searched for? Have you tried to search for basic OOP things like  how to call method in different class?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
I wouldn't use this method there.

`Update_LeadInfo` doesn't seem to use any methods from `RadForm1` besides those `TextBox.Text` objects.

Create another class with paremeters for accessing the Database, e.g.

```
public static class DatabaseAccess{

    private static string ConString = "<SOMECONSTRING>";
    public static void Update_LeadInfo(LeadInfo infoObj){ //Don't mix CamelCase and _ Case Notation
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
        {
           MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
           cmd.Connection = cn;
           cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Leads SET CVR = ('" + infoObj.CVR + "'), Firma = ('" + infoObj.Firma + "'), Nummer = ('" + infoObj.Nummer + "'), Addresse = ('" + infoObjAddresse + "'), Postnr = ('" + infoObj.Postnr + "'), Bynavn = ('" + infoObj.By + "'), Noter = ('" + infoObj.Noter + "'), Afholdt = ('" + infoObj.Afholdt + "'), Email = ('" + infoObj.Email + "'), Slut_Dato = ('" + infoObj.SlutDato + "')  WHERE UniqueID = ('" + infoObj.UniqueID + "');";
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           cmd.Dispose();
           cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

You `LeadInfo` class:

```
 public class LeadInfo{
     public string CVR {get;set}
     ...
     public string Afholdt {get;set;}
 }
```

And use **Parameterized Queries**!

Instead of `cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Leads SET CVR = ('" + infoObj.CVR + "'), Firma = ('" + infoObj.Firma + "'), Nummer = ('" + infoObj.Nummer + "'), Addresse = ('" + infoObjAddresse + "'), Postnr = ('" + infoObj.Postnr + "'), Bynavn = ('" + infoObj.By + "'), Noter = ('" + infoObj.Noter + "'), Afholdt = ('" + infoObj.Afholdt + "'), Email = ('" + infoObj.Email + "'), Slut_Dato = ('" + infoObj.SlutDato + "')  WHERE UniqueID = ('" + infoObj.UniqueID + "');";`

Use:

```
string updateCommand = "UPDATE Leads SET CVR = @paramCVR, ..., WHERE UniqueID = @paramUniqueID;"
MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand(updateCommand);
m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramCVR", infoObj.CVR);
...
m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramUniqueID", infoObj.UniqueID);
```

---

To get access to another public **non-static** method, you have to reference it in the class you want to use it.

So when you initialize your `CustomAppointmentEditForm` now, you have to pass the `RadForm1` as a parameter.

Build as second constructor without the parameter, if you want to call `CustomAppointmentEditForm` like before.

Take this as an example:

```
RadForm1 radObj;

public CustomAppointmentEditForm(RadForm1 radObj)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.radObj = radObj;
}

private void SomeMethod()
{
    radObj.Update_LeadInfo();
}
```

And this is your call **from** `RadForm1`:

```
CustomAppointmentEditForm custForm = new CustomAppointmentEditForm(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `Update_LeadInfo()` seems like business logic, and you should not have business-logic in UI layer. If you move it to separate data access project, you can refactor your code like that:

**DataAccessLayer:**

```
class DataAdapter
{
    public void UpdateLeads(LeadsInfo info)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            cn.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Leads SET CVR = ('" + info.CVR + "'), Firma = ('" + info.Firma + "')," /* ... */;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    

            cmd.Dispose();
            cn.Close();
        } 
    }
}
```

**UI Layer:**

```
class RadForm1
{
    public RadForm1(DataAdapter adapter)
    {
        if (adapter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("adapter");

        InitializeComponent();
        this.Adapter = adapter
    }

    private void Update_LeadInfo()
    {
        this.Adapter.UpdateLeads(new LeadsInfo(
                          CVR: txtCVR.Text,
                          Firma: txtFirma.Text,
                          /* ... */));
    }
}

class CustomAppointmentForm
{
    public CustomAppointmentForm(DataAdapter adapter)
    {
        if (adapter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("adapter");

        InitializeComponent();
        this.Adapter = adapter
    }

    private void Update_LeadInfo()
    {
        this.Adapter.UpdateLeads(new LeadsInfo(
                          CVR: txtCVR.Text,
                          Firma: txtFirma.Text,
                          /* ... */));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, wanted to mention this, too. But you were faster +1